# Is it possible to link to the reputation tab on <user who clicks the link>'s profile?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I was writing a comment on a meta post to the effect of:

> A user could also visit their [reputation tab](link) on their profile to view the breakdown of their rep changes.

I'd like to link to the reputation tab of **anyone** that clicks on the link (if they're logged in) - at the moment I can only seem to link directly to *one* user's rep tab.

I've tried various variations of `/users?tab=reputation`, but nothing seems to work for me.

Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
http://[site here]/users/current?tab=reputation
```

Usage:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation